# Google Maps API get a polyline from KML

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

I have loaded a KML file into a Google map using both V3 and geoxml3. The file contains one line, saved from Maps walking directions. I want to add mile markers to the line, but I can't find any documentation on how to get a polyline from the KmlLayer (or from the geoXML3 object).

V3:

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://blah.kml');
layer.setMap(map);
```

geoXML3:

```
var kml_parser = new geoXML3.parser({
  map: map,
  processStyles: true,
  createMarker: add_marker
});
kml_parser.parse('blah.kml');
```

Does anyone know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Polyline is accessible in geoxml3 by:

```
kml_parser.docs[0].gpolylines[0]
```

or as a property of the placemark

```
kml_parser.docs[0].placemarks[0].polyline
```

(the Polylines are not accessible in KmlLayer, they are rendered on tiles)

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_elevation_linkto.html?filename=FlightAware_JBU670_KLAX_KJFK_20120229_kml.xml) from a search of SO for [google-maps-api-3] geoxml3 polyline)

Another example:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=k&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_IT_info_kmlC.xml

Comment: Hi, I have tried both lines, but there are no docs in the parser, so I'm getting a 'cannot read property of undefined' error. kml_parser.docs.length is 0. But the KML file is loading and displaying on the map... Any clues?

Comment: Hi, after stopping being lazy and checking the first example you posted, I managed to get the length using the afterParse option! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this topic, but what is the API documentation on GeoXML3? I would like to know the available constructs and methods (just like Java API documentation, if you know what I mean).